# Comparing equality by list property

Tags: c#, linq, list

I am trying to find the number of items in a list that differ in a property which itself is a list. I found this example using Linq [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/489258/linqs-distinct-on-a-particular-property):

```
List<Person> distinctPeople = allPeople
  .GroupBy(p => p.PersonId)
  .Select(g => g.First())
  .ToList();
```

This works nicely if the property `PersonId` is scalar. But in my case this does not work and in the following the items in `SelectedTargets` are always returned as distinct even though the `ListOfActions` is equal in all items:

```
List<Target> distinctTargets = SelectedTargets.GroupBy(p => p.ListOfActions).Select(g => g.First()).ToList();
```

If instead I pick the first item in `ListOfActions` it works:

```
List<Target> distinctTargets = SelectedTargets.GroupBy(p => p.ListOfActions[0]).Select(g => g.First()).ToList();
```

So how can I check for equality of the whole list `ListOfActions`? (it doesn't necessarily have to user Linq)

The definition of `SelectedTargets` is:

```
List<Target> SelectedTargets = new List<Target>();
```

and is DispensingActionList:

```
private DispensingActionList ListOfActions = new DispensingActionList();
public class DispensingActionList : List<DispensingAction>
    { ...
```

Comment: Why don't you just override the Equals() method for ListOfActions class?

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: Ok. I will remember that. Sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a custom `IEqualityComparer<T>` for the `GroupBy` overload which compares sequences. For example this which uses `Enumerable.SequenceEqual`:

```
public class SequenceComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<IEnumerable<T>>
{
    public bool Equals(IEnumerable<T> x, IEnumerable<T> y)
    {
        if (x == null && y == null) return true;
        if (x == null || y == null) return false;

        var comparer = EqualityComparer<T>.Default;
        return x.SequenceEqual(y, comparer);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(IEnumerable<T> items)
    {
        unchecked
        {
            int hash = 17;
            foreach (T item in items)
            {
                hash = hash * 23 + (item == null ? 0 : item.GetHashCode());
            }
            return hash;
        }
    }
}
```

Now this should work:

```
 List<Target> distinctTargets = SelectedTargets
    .GroupBy(p => p.ListOfActions, new SequenceComparer<DispensingAction>())
    .Select(g => g.First())
    .ToList();
```

Of course `DispensingAction` also needs to override `Equals` to compare the objects meaningfully and not only checks whether they're the same reference or not.

Comment: I just got around to trying this. It works nicely, so thanks! However I would prefer a solution, where I do not have to instantiate a new object (the SequenceComparer) to test equality, so that the Linq line would remain like this: `List<Target> distinctTargets = SelectedTargets.GroupBy(p => p.ListOfActions).Select(g => g.First()).ToList();` I overriding `Equals(IList<DispensingAction> obj)` and using the Linq-line as above, but it returns `false`. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`Enumerable.SequenceEqual<TSource>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb348567(v=vs.100).aspx)

You will have to override the `GetHashCode` and `Equals` methods for your types if you didn't do so yet.